# Нужны ли запятые в предложении? (3)

Tags: запятые

"Дети вышли во двор и увидели чем можно позаниматься".

Нужны ли запятые в предложении? Почему?

Answer (score 2):

*Дети вышли во двор и увидели, чем можно позаниматься.*

Единственная запятая отделяет придаточное предложение от главного. "Вышли" и "увидели" — однородные члены, поэтому перед и запятая не нужна.